# js prototype form not working

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

new poster, sorry if anything is wrong with my post.

I am trying to make a form with the js prototype framework but it isn't working. I was wondering if someone could help me by pointing me in the right direction. Any help is appreciated!

This is my code:

```
        function formsF() {
            var form = $('exampleForm');
            var message= '';
            var field = form.getElements();
            for (var i = 0; i < field.length; i++) {
                message += "Field Name : " + field[i].name + " Value : " + field[i].value + "\n";
            }
            alert(message);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="exampleForm" action="#" onsubmit="return false">
        Name: <input type="text" name="name" /><br/>
        Number: <input type="text" name="number" /><br/>
        Message: <input type="text" name="message" /><br/>
    </form>
    <input type="button" value="Result" onclick="formsF();"/>
</body>
```

Comment: `getElements()`? I don't understand what this is. it should be `childNodes()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure to include the **prototype cdn**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="prototype@*" data-semver="1.7.1+0" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prototype/1.7.1.0/prototype.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <form id="exampleForm" action="#" onsubmit="return false">
        Name:       <input type="text" name="name" />
      <br />

        Number:       <input type="text" name="number" />
      <br />

        Message:       <input type="text" name="message" />
      <br />
    </form>
    <input type="button" value="Result" onclick="formsF();" />
    <script>
          function formsF() {
            var form = $('exampleForm');
            var message= '';
            var field = form.getElements();
            for (var i = 0; i < field.length; i++) {
                message += "Field Name : " + field[i].name + " Value : " + field[i].value + "\n";
            }
            alert(message);
        }
    </script>
  </body>

</html>
```

It works for me. 
Here is the [plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/2DWj3TMV1s8XXV0Ttp0Z?p=preview)

Hope it works for you :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this `form.find("input").length` :

```
  var form = $('#exampleForm');
  var message = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < form.find("input").length; i++) {
     message += "Field Name : " + form.find("input")[i].name + " Value : " + form.find("input")[i].value + "\n";
  }
  alert(message);
```

It works for me. Here is the [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3jw7pfbb/)

Hope it works for you :)